# Special CSS Gradients with 2 colors

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have to create a button which should look like the image attached with css:

[image: Sample]

I have no problem to get the border-radius of course, but I have no idea how to achive the color?

I tried somehing like this:

```
.button {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 100%);
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

but it doesn't looks like the button at all :(. See also http://jsfiddle.net/mcqb6zf7/.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code just changing the `background` property, is something like this you want?

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  background: rgba(76, 76, 76, 1);
  /* Old Browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 12%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 25%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 39%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 60%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 76%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 1) 91%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)), color-stop(12%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1)), color-stop(91%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1)));
  /* Chrome, Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 12%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 25%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 39%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 60%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 76%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 1) 91%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 12%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 25%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 39%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 60%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 76%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 1) 91%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 12%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 25%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 39%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 60%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 76%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 1) 91%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* IE 10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 12%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 25%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 39%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 60%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 76%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 1) 91%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">This is a button</div>
```

Comment: Always here to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want something like this:

```css
.gradient {
  height: 100px; 
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(76,76,76,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(12%, rgba(89,89,89,1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(91%, rgba(28,28,28,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19,19,19,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=0 ); 
  }
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct as well, but I had to choose one of them ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I just did in 30 seconds with http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8og02fd3/

```
.grad{
    background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%, #595959 51%, #595959 51%, #000000 53%, #000000 53%, #111111 60%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(51%,#595959), color-stop(51%,#595959), color-stop(53%,#000000), color-stop(53%,#000000), color-stop(60%,#111111), color-stop(91%,#1c1c1c), color-stop(100%,#131313)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#595959 51%,#595959 51%,#000000 53%,#000000 53%,#111111 60%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#595959 51%,#595959 51%,#000000 53%,#000000 53%,#111111 60%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#595959 51%,#595959 51%,#000000 53%,#000000 53%,#111111 60%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000000 0%,#595959 51%,#595959 51%,#000000 53%,#000000 53%,#111111 60%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

<span class="grad"> </span>
```

Should look the same?

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct as well, but I had to choose one of them ;)

Comment: No problem, I tried to get it looking at close as possible! :D